# Uniqueness of the maximum of a multi-dimensional function

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, convex-optimization

I have a somewhat complicated function of $M+1$ variables, which looks as follows.

$$f (x_0, x_1, x_2, \dots, x_M) = \sum_{i=1}^{N_A} \ln \left[1 - \text{erf}\left(x_0 + \sum_{j=1}^M a_{ij} x_j\right) \right] + \sum_{i=1}^{N_B} \ln \left[1 + \text{erf}\left(x_0 + \sum_{j=1}^M b_{ij} x_j\right) \right].$$

All is real here, but in in principle other than that there are no restrictions  on the possible values of the coefficients $a_{ij}$ and $b_{ij}$. $N_A$ and $N_B$ are in general some "larger" numbers (say, at least on the order of 100 or 1000), while $M$ tends to be pretty small, say for example 5 to 10 or so. Not that it should matter, but to add some context, this is actually a likelihood expression for some model.

Now my question is, is this a concave function with a unique maximum? Intuitively, the answer seems to be yes, and "numerical evidence" hints to the same direction, but I have a hard time proving it rigorously. I tried to calculate the Hessian, and eventually a general expression for its eigenvalues (which should all be negative in case my assumptions holds true), but it was just too much.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Thanks,
Lennex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sum of concave functions is concave, and $\ln(1+\text{erf}(t))$ and $\ln(1-\text{erf}(t))$ are easily seen to be concave.  So your function is concave.
Moreover, since $\ln(1+\text{erf}(t))$ and $\ln(1-\text{erf}(t))$ are strictly concave,
the only way for a maximum of your function (assuming it exists) to be non-unique would be for all the $x_0 + \sum_j a_{ij} x_j$ and all the $x_0 + \sum_j b_{ij} x_j$ to be equal
at two different points, i.e. the matrix $\pmatrix{1 & A\cr 1 & B\cr}$ to have rank $< M+1$, where $A$ and $B$ are the matrices of coefficients $a_{ij}$ and $b_{ij}$, and the $1$'s are column vectors of all $1$'s.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Intuitively, I knew that both sums, having only contributions from concave functions, should be concave as well, since they are both monotonic.  However, I was not sure if the some of a increasing concave function and a decreasing one would still be concave.